# Create Type that consists of readonly properties from imported classes

Tags: typescript

given classes like the following

```
class Dog {
   public readonly key:string = 'dog'
}

class Cat {
   public readonly key:string = 'cat'
}

export default [new Dog(), new Cat()]
```

is it possible to import those into another file, treat them as a const, and derive a type from their `key`?

```
import animals from '...'

type AnimalKeys = typeof animals[number]['key'] // type string
```

the type `AnimalKeys` is `string`. I'm hoping for the type to be `'dog' | 'cat'`

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNTAHArgIxAEthoAnAUzABN4A7EAT2gGtyGAuCAF1MNuQC80AOQ1EwtAF80aUJBgBhMF1QZs%20IiQrU6jFm048%20gkcGUTpsut2hhahALZgQMIQG1a5AO5wkACgBKABpoTx8lLkCAXRkuBixyaABBeycQAGk2V2g4hPgAM1tU5wgPHAc8clIot2FWBmEo6AB6Zpz4xO5efjQgA)

Comment: the type `AnimalKeys` is `string`. I'm hoping for the type to be `'dog' | 'cat'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't type them as a string.

```
class Dog {
   public readonly key = 'dog' as const
}

class Cat {
   public readonly key = 'cat' as const
}

const animals = [new Dog(), new Cat()]

type AnimalKeys = typeof animals[number]['key'] // type 'cat' | 'dog'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNTAHArgIxAEthoAnAUzABN4A7EAT2gGtymBeaAchsS%20kjRgdCABc0AXzRpQkGAGEwo1Bmz4iJCtTqMWbaJy7Al-QcNpjJ082IG1CAWzAgYnANq1yAdzhIAFACUADTQnj6KooEAutKiDFjk0ACC9k4gANJsrtBxCfAAZnaOzhAeOA545KRRblysDFxR0AD0zTnxiWKkhLSIaEA)

Comment: perfect! Thanks so much